# Lot of bluescreens while not using laptop

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, bsod

For a while now i'm having problems with a lot of BSOD. They mostly occur when not using the laptop at all. The DUMP files seem to tell me it has to do with the memory, but they have both been replaced. My last guess is that the SDD is broken or gone bad.

The bluescreen vary from Memory_Managment to Driver IRQL not less or equal.

Anyone who knows the problem?

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (d1)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If kernel debugger is available get stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffffc0cd2a48ff8, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000001, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
Arg4: ffffd100d455b98a, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for win32k.sys

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 3999

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 17255

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 546

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 29700

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 83

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: vb_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2019-12-06T14:06:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.19041.1


BUGCHECK_CODE:  d1

BUGCHECK_P1: fffffc0cd2a48ff8

BUGCHECK_P2: 2

BUGCHECK_P3: 1

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffd100d455b98a

WRITE_ADDRESS: fffff80768cfa390: Unable to get MiVisibleState
Unable to get NonPagedPoolStart
Unable to get NonPagedPoolEnd
Unable to get PagedPoolStart
Unable to get PagedPoolEnd
unable to get nt!MmSpecialPagesInUse
 fffffc0cd2a48ff8 

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

TRAP_FRAME:  ffffd100d0db1600 -- (.trap 0xffffd100d0db1600)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000109
rdx=a3a0105965ece921 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=ffffd100d455b98a rsp=ffffd100d0db1798 rbp=ffffd100d0db1819
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=f5f927bc857a27db r10=fffffc0cd2a48ff8
r11=0000000000000002 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
ffffd100`d455b98a 498902          mov     qword ptr [r10],rax ds:fffffc0c`d2a48ff8=????????????????
Resetting default scope

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd100`d0db14b8 fffff807`68408c69     : 00000000`0000000a fffffc0c`d2a48ff8 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000001 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd100`d0db14c0 fffff807`68404f69     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
ffffd100`d0db1600 ffffd100`d455b98a     : ffffd100`d455b11a 00000000`0000000c ffffa38c`f5ea8578 00000000`00000002 : nt!KiPageFault+0x469
ffffd100`d0db1798 ffffd100`d455b11a     : 00000000`0000000c ffffa38c`f5ea8578 00000000`00000002 ffffd100`d4243bd1 : 0xffffd100`d455b98a
ffffd100`d0db17a0 00000000`0000000c     : ffffa38c`f5ea8578 00000000`00000002 ffffd100`d4243bd1 00000000`00000101 : 0xffffd100`d455b11a
ffffd100`d0db17a8 ffffa38c`f5ea8578     : 00000000`00000002 ffffd100`d4243bd1 00000000`00000101 fffff807`683f6cf0 : 0xc
ffffd100`d0db17b0 00000000`00000002     : ffffd100`d4243bd1 00000000`00000101 fffff807`683f6cf0 fffffc0c`d2a4fb90 : 0xffffa38c`f5ea8578
ffffd100`d0db17b8 ffffd100`d4243bd1     : 00000000`00000101 fffff807`683f6cf0 fffffc0c`d2a4fb90 00000000`8768568e : 0x2
ffffd100`d0db17c0 00000000`00000101     : fffff807`683f6cf0 fffffc0c`d2a4fb90 00000000`8768568e 00000045`00000001 : 0xffffd100`d4243bd1
ffffd100`d0db17c8 fffff807`683f6cef     : fffffc0c`d2a4fb90 00000000`8768568e 00000045`00000001 00000000`0001c80b : 0x101
ffffd100`d0db17d0 fffffc0c`d2a4fb90     : 00000000`8768568e 00000045`00000001 00000000`0001c80b a3a01059`65ece921 : nt!KiBugCheckReturn+0x1b
ffffd100`d0db17d8 00000000`8768568e     : 00000045`00000001 00000000`0001c80b a3a01059`65ece921 00000000`00000000 : 0xfffffc0c`d2a4fb90
ffffd100`d0db17e0 00000045`00000001     : 00000000`0001c80b a3a01059`65ece921 00000000`00000000 f5f927bc`857a27db : 0x8768568e
ffffd100`d0db17e8 00000000`0001c80b     : a3a01059`65ece921 00000000`00000000 f5f927bc`857a27db ffffd100`d4540398 : 0x00000045`00000001
ffffd100`d0db17f0 a3a01059`65ece921     : 00000000`00000000 f5f927bc`857a27db ffffd100`d4540398 a38cf672`2900012f : 0x1c80b
ffffd100`d0db17f8 00000000`00000000     : f5f927bc`857a27db ffffd100`d4540398 a38cf672`2900012f 00000000`0000ffff : 0xa3a01059`65ece921


SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!KiPageFault+469

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.19041.985

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  469

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  AV_nt!KiPageFault

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {ec3e2762-48ae-ffe9-5b16-fbcb853e8320}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: I would use WinDBG to determine the cause.  We won't be able to narrow down the possible reasons for the BSOD without additional information.

Comment: I provided the DUMP files in the edited post. Is this possible to work with?

Comment: "My last guess is that the SDD is broken "   <-- Run the PC Manufacturer's Diagnostic App and test the hardware including the drive.

Comment: How can i provide you guys the WinDBG information?

Comment: @JelleWouter - You most definitely did not provide the dump files.  We don't necessary need the files, we need you to provide the information, after you run WinDBG against the files yourself.  Hopefully, you don't provide us hundreds of lines of text, that just to much information.  There are plenty of questions with answers on how to use WinDBG.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand that. I provided the last WinDBG one in the edited question

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a driver problem, either a corrupt driver or a poorly written one (less likely).

I myself would run the Driver Verifier tool.  You can find information on this tool at http://www.carrona.org/verifier.html

If for some reason, you still "blue screen".. you should be able to either get a stack dump better than the one you provided or a pointer to the driver file that is causing the problem.